# How to compare 2 InputStreams of every entry in a zip file

Tags: java, zip, inputstream

I have 2 zip files that contain a folder with 2 text files.

my first zip file:

```
fodler1
|_ file1.txt
|_ file2.txt
```

my second zip file:

```
folder1
|_ file1.txt
|_ file2.txt
```

Both zip files are passed as a Byte Array. I working on a way to compare every entry in those 2 zip files. So if files are named the same but have different content, the function should return false. This is my approach:

```
private void compareZip (byte[] zip1, byte[] zip2) throws IOException{

        ZipInputStream zipStream1 = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zip1));
        HashMap <String, InputStream> allEntries1 = new HashMap<String, InputStream>();
        ZipEntry entry1 = null;

        //Save InputStream of every entry in zip1
        while ((entry1 = zipStream1.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            allEntries1.put(entry1.getName(), zipStream1);
            zipStream1.closeEntry();
        }

        ZipInputStream zipStream2 = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zip2));
        HashMap <String, InputStream> allEntries2 = new HashMap<String, InputStream>();
        ZipEntry entry2 = null;

        //Save InputStream of every entry in zip2
        while ((entry2 = zipStream2.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            allEntries2.put(entry2.getName(), zipStream2);
            zipStream2.closeEntry();
        }

        //Returns true although files have different content
        isEqual(allEntries1.get("folder1/file1.txt"), allEntries2.get("folder1/file1.txt"));


        zipStream1.close();
        zipStream2.close(); 
}
```

The function `isEqual` compares 2 InputStreams:

```
private static boolean isEqual(InputStream i1, InputStream i2)
                throws IOException {

            ReadableByteChannel ch1 = Channels.newChannel(i1);
            ReadableByteChannel ch2 = Channels.newChannel(i2);

            ByteBuffer buf1 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);
            ByteBuffer buf2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024);

            try {
                while (true) {

                    int n1 = ch1.read(buf1);
                    int n2 = ch2.read(buf2);

                    if (n1 == -1 || n2 == -1) return n1 == n2;

                    buf1.flip();
                    buf2.flip();

                    for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(n1, n2); i++)
                        if (buf1.get() != buf2.get())
                            return false;

                    buf1.compact();
                    buf2.compact();
                }

            } finally {
                if (i1 != null) i1.close();
                if (i2 != null) i2.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not just compare the actual ZIP files? Or, why not compare each entry byte by byte until you find a mismatch? There is certainly no need to load the whole thing into memory once, let alone twice.

Comment: Thats not an option. I need know which files are different

Comment: So, sigh, why not compare each entry byte by byte until a mismatch?

Comment: Can you show me how? I need to know at which entry there is a mismatch

Comment: Err, compare each entry byte by byte until there is a mismatch? Instead of loading everything into memory? How many times does this have to be stated? What part of it don't you understand?